# Sign up process with Stored Procedure

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli, procedure

Im trying to install this Procedure in my php website. I tried to read a lot of topics, but is not working. The php code doesn't work.
Thanks for helping me!

Here is my stored procedure:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`dba233`@`%%` PROCEDURE `sp_IncluUser`(IN u_Name TEXT, IN u_Email TEXT, IN u_CodAcess TEXT, OUT Result boolean, Out Message TEXT, OUT QtCli int)
BEGIN
  Declare QtClient Int;
  Declare QtUser Int;
  Declare Erro        boolean default False;

  DECLARE exepction SMALLINT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET excessao = 1;

  SET Result = True;

  SELECT COUNT(*) into QtdeCliente
    FROM Nuvem_Client
    WHERE  u_CodAcesso = Cod_Acesso;
  IF (QtdeClient = 0) THEN
     SET Result = False;
     SET Message = 'Acess code invalid.';
  END IF;

Set QtCli = 999;

  IF Result = True THEN
     SELECT COUNT(*) into QtdeUsuario
       FROM Nuvem_Users
       WHERE  Email = u_Email;
Set QtCli = QtdeUsuario;
     IF (QtdeUsuario > 0) THEN
        SET Result = False;
        SET Message = 'Email already registered';
     END IF;
  END IF;

  IF Result = True THEN
     IF (u_Nome = "" OR u_Email = "") THEN

        SET Result = False;
        SET Message = 'Invalid';
     END IF;
  END IF;

  IF Result = True THEN
     START TRANSACTION;

     INSERT INTO db_Users ( `Name`, `Name_user`, `Email`, `password`, `Cod_Tipo_User`, `DtInclusao`)
     VALUES                     ( u_Name,  u_Name,         u_Email,   '',     '6', Now());
     IF excessao = 1 THEN
        SET Result = False;
        SET Message = 'Error';
        ROLLBACK;
     ELSE
        SELECT DISTINCT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @idUsuario FROM Nuvem_Users;
        IF excessao = 1 THEN
           SET Result = False;
           SET Message = 'Error';
           ROLLBACK;
        ELSE
           Insert into Nuvem_Users_Unity (Cod_User, Cod_Unity) 
               (SELECT @idUsuar, Cod_Unidade FROM Nuvem_Unity_Client UniCli
                   inner join Nuvem_Client Cli on UniCli.Cod_business = Cli.Cod_Empresa
                   where Cli.Cod_Acess = u_CodAcess);
           IF excessao = 1 THEN
              SET Result = False;
              SET Message = 'error' ;
              ROLLBACK;
           ELSE
              SET Result = True;
              SET Message = 'successfull ';
              COMMIT;
           END IF;
        END IF;
     END IF;
  END IF;

  END
```

there is a lot of mistakes in the name of tables and other things. Its because i want to kept the information for me because its from a client. 
I will change everything, no problem... i just want to know which php code i need to put to run this procedure. I dont want to know just the answer, you can just give me a tip and i will go to search.

Thank you guys! I need your help.

Comment: Doesn't work is a very broad statement. What exactly does not work? What errors are you getting/seeing?

Comment: _"i just want to know which php code i need to put to run this procedure"_ - have you tried searching for something like _"executing mysqli stored procedures"_? And is it the procedure that doesn't work or is it your (not added) attempt in PHP that doesn't work?

Comment: Hint: use PDO.  Code might look like: $pdo->exec(...);

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)